# Question on workflow Bookmarks

Tags: c#, workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I want to know how can i pass more than one Input Argument in a workflow bookmark. i have this code

```
   public sealed class CodeActivity1 : NativeActivity<String>
{
    [RequiredArgument]
    public InArgument<string> BookmarkName { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {

        context.CreateBookmark(BookmarkName.Get(context),
            new BookmarkCallback(OnResumeBookmark));
    }

    // NativeActivity derived activities that do asynchronous operations by calling 
    // one of the CreateBookmark overloads defined on System.Activities.NativeActivityContext 

    protected override bool CanInduceIdle
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void OnResumeBookmark(NativeActivityContext context, Bookmark bookmark, object obj)
    {
        Result.Set(context, (string)obj);
    }
}
```

When I resume it like app.ResumeBookmark("Test", "inputTest");. But what if i have for example 2 output Arguments like

```
        public InArgument<string> BookmarkName { get; set; }
        public OutArgument<string> Test1 {get; set;}
        public OutArgument<string> Test2 {get; set;}
```

How can i call this bookmark with app.ResumeBookmark()? and set the 2 OutArguments with stirngs from outside?. Like app.ResumeBookmark("Test","Inputtest1","Inputtest2")?
Thx for your time

Answer (score 3):

You can pass any object you want into the ResumeBookmark() call. So just create a class with three properties and use an instance of that class.

Comment: Hmm ok, But how can i access this object inside the Activity in order to access the members of the instance?

Comment: Its the last parameter passed to the OnResumeBookmark() as an object. Just cast it to the right type and you are done.

Comment: ok if a have a class Test with 2 members string S1 and S2. and i pass it inside the activity app.ResumeBookmark(Test);. Inside the Activity how can i set the OutArgument<string> Test1 with the value of S1?.

Comment: Test1.Set(context, ((Test)obj).S1);

Comment: If i have a Test3 which is DateTime type,public OutArgument<DateTime> Test3 { get; set; }, i am trying to cast it inside with Test3.Set(context, ((NewDates)obj).StartDate) and i get an Error Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'NewDates'. Bear in mind that NewDates.StartDate is also DateTime type. Can you help me ?

Comment: Sounds like whatever value you are using with ResumeBookmark() is a string, not a NewDates type.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
    public void OnResumeBookmark(NativeActivityContext context, Bookmark bookmark, object obj)    {        
        Test t = obj as Text;
        context.SetValue(this.Test1, t.S1);    
        context.SetValue(this.Test2, t.S2);    
    }
```

Comment: If i have a Test3 which is DateTime type,public OutArgument<DateTime> Test3 { get; set; }, i am trying to cast it inside with Test3.Set(context, ((NewDates)obj).StartDate) and i get an Error Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'NewDates'. Bear in mind that NewDates.StartDate is also DateTime type. Can you help me ?